# Meteor find on an array

Tags: meteor

I'm trying iterate on an array and return my collection

I have the following

```
Meteor.publish('collaborators', function() {
  var topics = Topics.findOne({$or:[{
    userId: this.userId,
  }, {
    collaboratorsIds: this.userId,
  }, {
    inviteeId:this.userId,
  }]});

  return Collaborators.find({
    topicId: topics._id,
  });
});
```

`topics` is an array and I would like the Collaborators.find to iterate and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator to include all elements of an array of `_id`s:

```
return Collaborators.find({
  topicId: {$in: _.pluck(topics, '_id')},
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not working 

return Collaborators.find({topicId: {$in: _.pluck(topics, '_id')}});

Comment: Right, you said that `topics` is an array, but now I see that it's a result of `findOne`, so it should be an object. So how is this object structured and what do you want to iterate on?

Comment: Yes your right, I have topics setup wrong. I need to get all the users topics and then return collaborators

Comment: So you should probably replace `Topics.findOne(...);` with `Topics.find(...).fetch();`.

Comment: thanks that's perfect everything is working great now